# server_name not resolving to specified port in NGINX configuration

Tags: docker, nginx

I am running an **nginx** container on my server to host a static page

#### File Structure

```
app/
 |__nginx/
 |    |__nginx.conf
 |__docker-compose.yml
 |__index.html
```

#### nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name www.my-website.cf my-website.cf;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/my-website;
    index index.html;
}
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/share/nginx/html/my-website
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

When trying to `curl localhost:8000` from the host machine I get the correct response which is the webpage

However when trying to `curl my-website.cf` I get

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to my-website.cf port 80: Connection refused
```

My question is why is the `server_name` I specified in my `nginx.conf` file not resolving to the port I specified which is 8000

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ngixn in container, you will have to expose port 80.
The question is why your nginx listen on 8000, but it is different task.

Change your docker-compose.yml like this :

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/share/nginx/html/my-website
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Last but not at least is opening firewall.